# Hardhat local network keys generation

Tags: etherscan, addresses, hash, hash-algorithm, hardhat

I noticed the generation of **Hardhat local Etheruem network** keys are found on the **Mainnet**.

### Example:

After running `npx hardhat node`.

```
Accounts
========
Account #0: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266 (10000 ETH)
Private Key: 0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80
```

The link of the same address in the Mainnet: https://etherscan.io/address/0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266

Any explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hardhat comes with a set of default accounts, which can be shown by using the `npx hardhat accounts` command.

You'll see that the first of the default accounts is the one you've pointed to.

The transactions on the mainnet have presumably happened in error: people have sent transactions to the address thinking they were still on a test network (for example).

Given that the private key is public - as in your snippet - anyone can then drain the funds.

```
$ npx hardhat accounts
0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266  <---
0x70997970C51812dc3A010C7d01b50e0d17dc79C8
0x3C44CdDdB6a900fa2b585dd299e03d12FA4293BC
0x90F79bf6EB2c4f870365E785982E1f101E93b906
0x15d34AAf54267DB7D7c367839AAf71A00a2C6A65
0x9965507D1a55bcC2695C58ba16FB37d819B0A4dc
0x976EA74026E726554dB657fA54763abd0C3a0aa9
0x14dC79964da2C08b23698B3D3cc7Ca32193d9955
0x23618e81E3f5cdF7f54C3d65f7FBc0aBf5B21E8f
0xa0Ee7A142d267C1f36714E4a8F75612F20a79720
0xBcd4042DE499D14e55001CcbB24a551F3b954096
0x71bE63f3384f5fb98995898A86B02Fb2426c5788
0xFABB0ac9d68B0B445fB7357272Ff202C5651694a
0x1CBd3b2770909D4e10f157cABC84C7264073C9Ec
0xdF3e18d64BC6A983f673Ab319CCaE4f1a57C7097
0xcd3B766CCDd6AE721141F452C550Ca635964ce71
0x2546BcD3c84621e976D8185a91A922aE77ECEc30
0xbDA5747bFD65F08deb54cb465eB87D40e51B197E
0xdD2FD4581271e230360230F9337D5c0430Bf44C0
0x8626f6940E2eb28930eFb4CeF49B2d1F2C9C1199
```