# New Metamask created account appears to have previous transaction [ Rinekby ]

Tags: metamask, rinkeby

I have just created a new account on metamask and to my surprise i can see a lot of transactions to and from the account on test (rinekby) network.

Isn't the account brand new ?

If it has previous transactions that probably means some one has the private key as well.

```
0xBcd4042DE499D14e55001CcbB24a551F3b954096
```

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xbcd4042de499d14e55001ccbb24a551f3b954096

[image]

Comment: That address is generated by a seed phrase used in hardhat testing. See this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/94899. I'd suggest to create a new seed phrase.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. I found the account on list of hardhat generated ones. Thanks @Ismael !